# How to finish of a validation in php?

Tags: php, mysql, validation

I just need help on finishing this validation I have where the php checks to see if there are any errors when user submits form:

```
$errors = array();


      if (!$getcourseid){
          $errors[] = "You must enter in Course's ID";
  }else if (!$getcoursename){
      $errors[] = "You must enter in Course's Name";
  }else if (!$getduration){
          $errors[] = "You must select Course's Duration";
      }     

      if(!$errors) {

     $insertsql = "
    INSERT INTO Course
        (CourseNo, CourseName, Duration)
      VALUES
        (?, ?, ?)
    ";
    if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql)) {
      // Handle errors with prepare operation here
    }                                           

    $insert->bind_param("sss", $getcourseid, $getcoursename, $getduration);

    $insert->execute();

    if ($insert->errno) {
      // Handle query error here
    }

    $insert->close();

     // don't use $mysqli->prepare here
$query = "SELECT CourseNo FROM Course WHERE CourseNo = ?";
// prepare query
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$stmt->bind_param("s",$getcourseid);
// execute query
$stmt->execute(); 
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$stmt->bind_result($dbCourseId);
//get number of rows
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows();  

          }

$form = "
<form action='" . htmlentities($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "' method='post'>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td id='errormsg'>$errormsg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Course ID:</td>
  <td><input type='text' name='courseid' value='$getcourseid' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Course Name:</td>
  <td><input type='text' id='nameofcourse' name='coursename' value='$getcoursename' /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>Duration (Years):</td>
  <td>{$durationHTML}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td><input type='submit' value='Create Course' name='createbtn' /></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>";

  echo $form;
```

My question is that I want to display a success message if there are no errors and the database stuff have been successfully completed or display an error message if the form has been completed with no errors but the database stuff could not be completed. Also I want to display all messages to the `$errormsg` variable? Can I ask how that can be done?

Below is something I want to achieve but not sure if its correct for the code above:

```
               if ($numrows == 1){

               $errormsg = "<span style='color: green'>Course " . $getcourseid .  " - "  . $getcoursename . " has been Created</span>";
               $getcourseid = "";
               $getcoursename = "";
               $getduration = "";

           }else{

               $errormsg = "An error has occured, Course has not been Created";

           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic goes like this, suppose you are having an array of errors simply you can do this

```
if(empty($errormsg)) {
   //Go Ahead
} elseif(!empty($errormsg)) {
  //if(isset($errormsg['index'])) {
     echo 'Error'; 
  }
}
```

Detailed Explanation

Supposing you have 3 errors like

```
$errors[0] = 'Username is invalid';
$errors[1] = 'Password is invalid';
$errors[2] = 'Third error';

if(empty($errors)) {
   //Go Ahead
} else {
    if(isset($errors[0])) {
       echo $errors[0]; 
    } elseif (isset($errors[1])) {
       echo $errors[1];
    } elseif (isset($errors[1])) {
       echo $errors[1]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, is it ok if you use update my code so I can see what I need to do for it because  I am still confused, would that logic store every error in the `$errormsg` variable? Is that echo 'Error' suppose to be the `an error has occurred...` message or is it suppose to be the indvidual errors from the errors array outputted? Also on top of page I have `$errormsg = (isset($errormsg)) ? $errormsg : '';` so Im guessing I don't need the isset you have commented?

Comment: @user1881090 edited my answer, hope u understand now

Comment: I understand now, just need to ask that in the if statement I have on top of page do I need to change $errors[]... to $errors[1]...., then $errors[2] etc.  Just making sure

Comment: no if you don't specify the index no, it auto indexes kinda 0,1,2,3, you can also specify particular index name like `$error['inval_username'];` instead of `$error[0];` which doesn't make any sense

Comment: Oh did not know that, that is pretty cool. One last little question, where does the error message `An error has occured...` go? I have marked your answer

Comment: @user1881090 it dependss on you when you want to shoot that error, you can simply store it in a variable and later echo it inside your template whenever that error is set, use sessions for better error handling, read few articles on error handling, might help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

Try with jQuery:

**In test.php**

```
...
$data['status'] = 1; // Status of the operation (1: Ok, 0: Error)
$data['msg'] = $msg; // Error message or success
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

**In test.js:**

```
$("#send").click(function () {
    $.post('test.php', $('#yourForm').serialize(), function(data){
        if(data.status == 1){
            $('#result').show().addClass('success').html(data.msg);
        }
        else{
            $('#result').show().addClass('error').html(data.msg);
        }
    }, "json");
    return false;
});
```

**In test.html:**

```
<form method="post" id="yourForm">
...
<input id="send" type="button"/>
<span id="result"></span>
</form>
```

**In test.css:**

```
.success{
    color: blue;
}
.error{
    color: red;
}
```

Hope that helps somewhat.

Regards.